# Stability of nonlinear planar map fixed points.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Got the map:

$$x_{n+1} = x_ne^{2-x_n-y_n}$$
$$y_{n+1} = y_ne^{x_n-1}$$

I found the fixed points (0,0), (2,0), (1,1).

For the stability I have the Jacobian to find eigenvalues as:

$$J = \begin{pmatrix} e^{2-x-y} + xe^{2-x-y} - \lambda & -xe^{2-x-y} \\ye^{x-1} & e^{x-1} - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

Now, I thought to sub in the fixed points and then apply the Jury conditions. i.e. for the fixed point (0,0) the Jacobian is:

$$J = \begin{pmatrix} e^2 - \lambda & 0 \\0 & e^{-1} - \lambda \end{pmatrix}$$

Which leads to eigenvalues:

$$\lambda^2 - (e^{-1}+e^2)\lambda + e$$

I think from the jury condition I could say $e > 1$ and so at least one root is unstable. However in the solutions, it's simply said that:

$$J = \begin{pmatrix} e^2 & 0 \\0 & e^{-1} \end{pmatrix}$$

Hence $\lambda_1 =e^2 > 1$ therefore unstable. Is this some sort of trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion comes from looking at the eigenvalues before evaluating the Jacobian at a point.

The Jacobian is a matrix 
\begin{equation}
 J(x,y) = \left(\begin{array}\ (1+x)e^{2-x-y} & -xe^{2-x-y}\\ ye^{x-1} & e^{x-1}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}
which when evaluated at $(0,0)$ produces 
\begin{equation}
 J(0,0) = \left(\begin{array}\ e^2 & 0\\ 0 & e^{-1}\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Clearly this has strictly real eigenvalues with $\lambda_1 =e^2 >1$ thus the fixed point at $(0,0)$ is unstable.